# Magento 2 not load google fonts google pagespeed

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to not load the 
    http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700

Because pagespeed gives a penalty for render blocking css...

Also maybe other tips and tricks for the render blocking JS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

call google font at bottom of page. just above  tag

like:

```
<style>
@import "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700"
</style>
```